# MVC3 MvcSiteMap()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVC3 razor view. MvcSitemapProvider dll version 3.1.0.0

When I use this `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMap()` in my razorview , I get the following error message

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView..ctor(System.String, System.String)'.
```

I have registered the namespace for:

```
<add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
<add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
```

In both of the web.config files  (root as well as the view web.config).

Is there anything else I need to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the MvcSitemapProvider.dll as reference within the project you are attempting to use it within?

I'm assuming you have not as its a two part step:

1. Add the dll as an [Assembly Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. Register the provider in your web.config

**Edit**:

As you mentioned that the dll is physically rendered, upon closer examination your setup of the web.config may be a little off. For reference here is the [Setup Guide](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Registering-the-provider).

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true"> 
  <providers> 
    <clear /> 
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
         /> 
  </providers> 
</siteMap>
```

It seems that you have only [registered the html helper](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-functions)s within the web.config

Comment: This is how my root web.config looks

Comment: That's fine but did you physically add the assembly reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yes, I have added reference to dll MvcSitemapProvider dll version 3.1.0.0

This project is an upgrade from MVC2 to MVC 3

Comment: Have updated my answer based upon your feedback as upon a closer review it seems your missing the actual registration of the provider within the web.config.

Comment: you are correct, when I register the provider I get rid of this error Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Mvc.WebFormView..ctor(System.String, System.Str'  but my sitemapprovider which was in MVC 2 has stopped working , here is how my web.sitemap looks like

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0"  >
    <siteMapNode >
      <siteMapNode  > 
          <siteMapNode />
          <siteMapNode >
           <siteMapNode/>
           </siteMapNode>
          <siteMapNode />
          <siteMapNode/>
          <siteMapNode/>
          <siteMapNode />
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode >
      <siteMapNode/>
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>

Answer (score 0):

Your root web.config should have this in the pages, namespaces node.

```
      <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
```

and also..

```
   <siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider"
           type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           siteMapFile="~/Site.sitemap" <!-- This can be changed depending on your .sitemap file -->
           securityTrimmingEnabled="true"
           cacheDuration="5"
           enableLocalization="true"
           scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true"
           skipAssemblyScanOn=""
           attributesToIgnore="bling"
           nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider"
           siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
```

And in your view web.config,

```
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
```

Make sure you have the newest version of MVC SiteMap from [here](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, in the shared _Layout, I have 
            <div id="breadcrumb">
                <div>
                    @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
                </div>
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this problem by adding the DisplayTemplates. How the models had to be displayed.

ex.:

```
@model SiteMapNodeModel

@if (Model.IsCurrentNode && Model.SourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString() != "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper")  { 
    <text>@Model.Title</text>
} else if (Model.IsClickable) {
    <a href="@Model.Url" class="@(Model.IsCurrentNode ? "selected" : string.Empty)" >@Model.Title</a>
}
else
{ 
    <text>@Model.Title</text>
}
```